# UnityScript "does not exist"

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I tried to add one of my scripts to a Unity project, but Unity claims that it does not exist. Now none of my scripts are working. I tried looking on the web, but apparently I'm the only person who uses UnityScript.

Here's the doorScript that started this problem:

```
#pragma strict

// Smoothly open a door
var smooth = 2.0;
private var open : boolean;
private var enter : boolean;
var say : String;

private var defaultRot : Vector3;
var openRot : Vector3;

function Start(){
defaultRot = transform.eulerAngles;
}

//Main function
function Update (){
if(open){
//Open door
transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, openRot,    Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}
else{
//Close door
transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, defaultRot,    Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}

if(Input.GetKeyDown("e") && enter){
open = !open;
}
}

function OnGUI(){
if(enter){
GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - 75, Screen.height - 100, 150, 30), say);
}
}

//Activate the Main function when player is near the door
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider){
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
enter = true;
}
}

//Deactivate the Main function when player is go away from door
function OnTriggerExit (other : Collider){
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
enter = false;
}
}
```

The file is named doorScript.js. It worked on my last project so if you want to take it go ahead but it won't work on my FPS project.

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not use javascript, it uses *UnityScript*. You need to encapsulate your script into a class.

```
#pragma strict

public class DoorScript extends MonoBehaviour
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Actually, it works now without the class. I don't know why it did not this afternoon and then decided to when I restarted my computer.